# How to select only id instead of print name in select options?

Tags: php, html, select

```
<select id="rightsid" name="rightsid">
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
        $admno=$row["adm_no"];
        $name=$row["name"];
?>
    <option id="<?php echo $admno;?>" name="<?php echo $admno;?>"><?php echo $admno;?> <?php echo $name;?></option>
<?php  
    }
?>
    <input type="submit" value="Show Rights">
</select>
```

This is my code. When I take the `value` of `select` to next page, it is taking both `name` and `admno` but I want to take only admno but here in dropdown list. I want to display both but want to carry only one. How to do this?

Comment: just put in whatever value you want to carry over.. no? you have options without values.. what values do you want to carry over?

Answer (score 2):

Within option value, write `$admo`. Try this:

```
<?php
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
      $admno    =    $row["adm_no"];
      $name     =    $row["name"];
      echo '<option id = "'.$admno.'" name = "'.$admno.'" value = "'.$admno.'" >' . $admno . $name . '</option>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use `value` in option as below

```
<select id="rightsid" name="rightsid">
<?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
        $admno=$row["adm_no"];
        $name=$row["name"];
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $admno;?>" id="<?php echo $admno;?>" name="<?php echo $admno;?>"><?php echo $admno;?> <?php echo $name;?></option>
<?php  
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option id="<?php echo $admno;?>" value="<?php echo $admno;?>"><?php echo $name;?></option>
```